# Add a field to serializer context

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a `retrieveAPIView` and I have to set one of its field to the `serializer_context`

```
class FoodRetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):

    serializer_class = serializers.FoodRetrieveSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = models.Food.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        query_params = self.request.query_params
        delivery_date = query_params.get("delivery_date")
        context["delivery_date"] = delivery_date
```

And in my serializer, I have to access the context

```
class FoodRetrieveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = FoodItemSerializer(many=True)


class FoodItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_item(self, obj):
    return ItemValueRetrieveSerializer(
        instance=obj.get_item(), many=False, context=self.context
    ).data



class ItemValueRetrieveSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    value = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_value(self, obj):
        delivery_date = self.context.get("delivery_date")
        food_value = obj.get_food_value(delivery_date=delivery_date)
```

I've been trying this way a couple of times but i can't still get the value of delivery_date in context. How can i do this? Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to return the context in `get_serializer_context(self)`.

Comment: I added the return, but the `query_params.get("check_in_date")` still return none.

Comment: I don't see the line `query_params.get("check_in_date")` in your code.

Comment: I've updated the view now. Tried refactoring my code awhile ago.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you're sending a GET request to an URL such as `http://localhost:8000/.../some_pk?delivery_date=2021-01-31` since Django expects this kind of date format by default.

Second point, don't forget to return the context at the end of `get_serializer_context`:

```py
class FoodRetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    # ...
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        query_params = self.request.query_params
        delivery_date = query_params.get("delivery_date")
        context["delivery_date"] = delivery_date
        return context
```

Third and last point, as you have nested serializer, you need to pass the context each time you call a child serializer as a domino effect:

```py
class FoodRetrieveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # don't forget to pass the context here
    items = FoodItemSerializer(many=True, context=self.context)


class FoodItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_item(self, obj):
        # This function looks weird to me, but I assume you know what you're doing
        return ItemValueRetrieveSerializer(
            instance=obj.get_item(), many=False, context=self.context
        ).data


class ItemValueRetrieveSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    value = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_value(self, obj):
        delivery_date = self.context.get("delivery_date")
        food_value = obj.get_food_value(delivery_date=delivery_date)
```

Also, *just a piece of advice*, the dictionary `get()` method accepts a second argument which is the default value in case the key does not exist. It's always better to explicitly give it even if it's `None`. And in this case, probably consider handling the None case by raising a HTTP 400 bad request error with a custom error message saying you need to give a delivery date (rather than a 500 server error).